# Having trouble overwriting raster layers default property sheet

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I need to Override the Property Sheet Dialog to display a custom property sheet that has a custom GUI built to analyse raster data based on transformed values.

Alternatively, if I can access the property sheet itself through a pointer from a raster layer and put a custom page with the GUI into the default property sheet that is shown when the layer is double clicked in the table of contents.

The key here is that the custom Sheet must be displayed when the item is double clicked in the Table of Contents.

[image: Default Spreedsheet]

[image: Overite Spreadsheet]

[image: Alternatively add new page to existing Property Sheet]

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've never done so not sure if I am suggesting a red herring?

You need to look at the page [Creating Property Pages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004s7000000) in the ArcObjects API help, from here there is a link to some sample code on a page called [Layer property page and property sheet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Layer_property_page_and_property_sheet/0001000000v1000000/).

Comment: I already know how to create a property page I just need it to over ride the default one. I've also read both of those articles